# Are <figure> and <figcaption> ignored by search engine crawlers?

Tags: seo

It is said that search engine crawlers would ignore heading titles (h1~h6) in `<figcaption>` because html5 outline algorithm doesn't parse them.

So we should avoid using `<figure>` or `<figcaption>`.  Is this true?

Update 1:
Google does index h1~h6 in `figcaption`.

Update 2:
To get the title more clear, it comes from an opinion:

1. Googlebot uses html5 outline algorithm to parse content
2. That algorithm ignores heading in figcaption
3. So we should not use h1~h6 in figcaption

Comment: When you are talking about the outline algorithm are you talking about the w3c guidance about how to use HTML 5 to make a document outline? [HTML 5.2: 4.3. Sections](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sections.html#creating-an-outline) or are you talking about accessibility guidelines such as [HTML 5's headings outline algorithm - ADG](https://www.accessibility-developer-guide.com/examples/headings/html-5-outline/)

Comment: We discussed this topic because of SEO. Accessibility is also a part of SEO, so I think both of them are considered.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what the html5 outline algorithm that you talk about in your question is?   Can you provide a link to it?

Comment: Through the discussions, we have referred to HTML5 outliner: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/html5-outliner/afoibpobokebhgfnknfndkgemglggomo and MDN's explanation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML_sections_and_outlines

So I think it's more for w3c guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any HTML element should be used for any application where it makes sense to do so according to the HTML specification without regard to SEO or how search engines use it. Doing so never does any harm and, at most, does good for the browser and the user.

Any advice otherwise is pure hogwash and that web site or person should be ignored into perpetuity.

Comment: I have tried that Google does index headings in `figcaption`.

To get the title more clear, it comes from a opinion:
1. Googlebot uses html5 outline algorithm to parse content
2. That algorithm ignores heading in figcaption
3. So we should not use h1~h6 in figcaption